# Pasar variable a jqueryui autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui

Quiero pasar una variable de un input de tipo texto a jQueryui autocomplete, pero creo que tengo la sintaxis mal o quizás no se pueda hacer.

El código que tengo es este:

```
$('#InPedido_DirEnvio').autocomplete({
        source:'./Scripts/Phps/Autocompletar.php?pag=autocompletar_dir_clientes&cli='+$('input[name=InPedido_idcliente]').val(),
        minLength:3,
        dataType: "json",
```

el valor del input como se puede ver lo estoy pasando con `$('input[name=InPedido_idcliente]').val()`
pero no se si eso es posible pasarlo en source, tengo mal la sintaxis o tengo que hacerlo de otra manera.

¿esto es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para estos casos tienes que generar tu propia funcion source llamando dentro de ella al source de verdad.

```
$("#InPedido_DirEnvio").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Scripts/Phps/Autocompletar.php?pag=autocompletar_dir_clientes&cli="+$('input[name=InPedido_idcliente]').val(),
        success: function(data) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
  },
  minLength: 3
});
```

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693560/how-do-i-pass-an-extra-parameter-to-jquery-autocomplete-field) puedes ver más formas de solucionarlo.

Comment: Perfecto :) pasa la variable sin problemas. Mil gracias me has salvado la vida 8)